# JSF navigation from action with param

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I have the following navigation-rule:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/pages/*</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>test</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/pages/test/edit.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

TestMB:

```
public String test() {
    return "test?id=1";
}
```

and test.xhtml:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{testMB.test}">click</h:commandLink>
```

But it is not working if `return "test?id=1";`. I do not want to use `return "/pages/test/edit.xhtml?id=1";`, I want to use the abstract name `test`.

Comment: Food for read: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15521451

Comment: @BalusC, I want to use it for forms. Thanks and you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking to add a GET parameter to the URL, know that you can't use the `<navigation-case>` (that is `test` in your example). The only way that'll work is if you had a specific URL/page as in:

```
  public String test() {

      return "edit.xhtml?id=1&faces-redirect=true";
  }
```

The redirection+parameter mechanism works only with a definite page/URL to direct to. It's not compatible with the JSF-provided `navigation-case` mechanism.

---

If for some reason, you require that the navigation case be the mode of navigation, you need to define the navigation parameter in your faces-config file:

```
    <to-view-id>/pages/test/edit.xhtml</to-view-id>
    <redirect>
        <view-param>
            <name>id</name>
            <value>1</value>
        </view-param>
    </redirect>
```

The `redirect` tag is what specifies the `faces-redirect` parameter, along with your desired GET parameter `id` .

---

An even better form is where you're not hard-coding the value, rather making it dynamic via a value-binding:

```
   <redirect>
        <view-param>
            <name>id</name>
            <value>#{yourBean.redirectValue}</value>
        </view-param>
    </redirect>
```